# Datatables change text color from parsed json

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I'm trying to change text color of rows with certain parsed json data.
If the `status` is `True` then text color should be `red`. I tried using `rowCallback` but instead it turns all row become red

Here what I tried

```
$('#tbldata').dataTable({
"data": jQuery.parseJSON(data.d),
"columns": [
            { "data": "user"},
            { "data": "userseries"},
            { "data": "invoice"}
        ],
        "ordering": true,
        "info": false,
        "searching": false,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "sDom": 'Rfrtlip',
        "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
         if (status= True) {
             $('td', row).css({ color: "red" });
         }
    });
```

This is my json object :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "user": All,
      "userseries": "6395637",
      "invoice": 200,
      "status": True
    },
    {
      "user": Bll,
      "userseries": "9473650",
      "invoice": 180,
      "status": False
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: maaaybe `if(status== True){...`?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes:

1. Your JSON sample is not valid JSON.

I assume an entry such as `"user": Bll` should be `"user": "Bll"`,

`"status": True` is also invalid. If the JSON actually contains `"status": "True"`, then you need to use `if (data.status === 'True') {...}`.

If the JSON actually contains `"status": true` then see the example below.

2. If you are already providing (valid) JSON to your DataTable, then you do not need to re-parse it - so you should not need `jQuery.parseJSON()`.
3. You have a missing `}` in your row callback code.
4. I recommend you use modern option names (for example `dom` instead of `sDom`). The old names still work, however - so this is optional.

Here is an example showing all the above points. I have provided some embedded test data in my example - obviously you will have to change that back to use your data source.

Click on the blue "run" button below to see the results:

```js
var dataSet = {
  "data": [
    {
      "user": "All",
      "userseries": "6395637",
      "invoice": 200,
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "user": "Bll",
      "userseries": "9473650",
      "invoice": 180,
      "status": false
    }
  ]
};
 
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tbldata').dataTable({
  "data": dataSet.data,
  "columns": [
    { "data": "user", "title": "Data" },
    { "data": "userseries", "title": "User Series" },
    { "data": "invoice", "title": "Invoice" }
  ],
  ordering: true,
  info: false,
  searching: false,
  stateSave: true,
  dom: 'Rfrtlip',
  rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
    if (data.status) {
      $('td', row).css({ color: "red" });
    }
  }
});

} );
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="tbldata" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Your snippet works